# DbFit - How to query 2 databases from different servers?

Tags: sql-server, dbfit

We can setup test and query one database on the server (or multiple dbs on the same server) using the foll.:

```
    !|dbfit.SQLServerTest|

!|Connect|RSSPL25|sa|sa|DatabaseB|

!|Query| select 'test' as x|
```

Within the same test, how do we query another database from a different server?

Any simple example will help me.

Comment: How have you tried previously to query 2 databases? Are you trying to do 1 select across 2 databases or are you performing to queries? This question needs additional information.

Comment: Have I tried? No, since all examples cover connection to one db, I am not sure how to go about using a 2nd db (on the same server or on another server)

Comment: 1 select across 2 dbs vs queries - I need both at some point

Comment: have you tried `select * from [database].[dbo].[table]`